# Download Binary Data as a File Via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, binary-data

I'm making an ajax call to an API that returns binary data. I'm wondering if its possible to take that binary data and display it for the client in a new window? This is what I'm doing right now. The problem is, the document opens up, but its completely blank.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: apiURL,
    data: xmlRequest,
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
        var bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder();

        // Append the binary data to the blob
        bb.append(xhr.responseText);

        var blobURL = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(bb.getBlob('application/pdf'));
        window.open(blobURL);
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS with IE?  If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773308/ie-https-generating-pdf-from-php-file-doesnt-work

Comment: Its a chrome extension, so I don't have to worry about IE.

Comment: do you have control of the server side implementation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I had to specify the responseType as 'array buffer':

```
function downloadPDF() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', API_URL, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder();
            bb.append(this.response); // Note: not xhr.responseText

            var blob = bb.getBlob('application/pdf');
            var blobURL = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);

            window.open(blobURL);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(createRequest());
}
```

Comment: How do you change the downloaded file name using this method?

Comment: using FileSaver will make this easier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211742/html5-saveas-support-in-google-chrome

Comment: I am gettign this error when included xhr.responseType `ERROR DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'arraybuffer').
    at XMLHttpRequest.x.onreadystatechange [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:11702:31)`

Comment: what's the `createRequest()` for?

Comment: after removing `createRequest()`, getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: window.WebKitBlobBuilder is not a constructor`