# html5 saveAs support in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-filesystem

I am trying to use `saveAs` interface as explained [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side)

For the moment, I only worry about Google Chrome, and I uses latest Canary (Version 27.0.1429.0 canary)

Qn1: the article says.

> The W3C File API includes a FileSaver interface, which makes saving
>   generated data as easy as saveAs(data, filename), though unfortunately
>   it will eventually be removed from the spec.

Why it would be removed?

Qn2: Below code.

```
if (window.saveAs) {
    window.saveAs(blob, name);
}else{
    console.log("saveAs not supported")
}
```

prints

```
saveAs not supported
```

So chrome doesn't support saveAs. That is not the impression I have reading many article online.

Comment: I would immediately assume because it would allow an attacker to save a malicious file on the user's computer.

Comment: @Daedalus: well its still not entirely impossible without the `saveAs()` function, just create a small fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/shivasaxena/qnYk4/3/

Comment: @Shiva - perfect, works great - you should post this as an alternative to a function that is going away.

Comment: @Shiva great solution but maybe not set it up to instantly download when you click on your link.

Answer (score 9):

this is a polyfill, as explained in the article. You have to load the javascript file listed in the article, save it in your resources and link to it in your code:
The repository is there:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

There are limitations in Chrome, though. If file already saved, the new saving name is incremented :
myFile(1), then myFile(2), etc.

I have now a bug on Chrome, which tells can it cannot OPEN the file, but it is just a false warning, as the file is well SAVED, which is the point.