# Download Binary Files with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to download binary files using Javascript.

I have a REST service that returns the binary data and i want to know if its possible to show the binary file, whichever the file extension.

This is my current code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("GET", requestUrl);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var ret = [];
    var len = this.responseText.length;
    var byte;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        byte = (this.responseText.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF) >>> 0;
        ret.push(String.fromCharCode(byte));
    }
    var data = ret.join('');
    data = "data:application/pdf;base64," + btoa(data);

    window.open(data, '_blank', 'resizable, width=1020,height=600');
}, false);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + client.accessToken);
xhr.overrideMimeType("octet-stream; charset=x-user-defined;");
xhr.send(null);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean "show"?

Comment: you should check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620497/download-binary-data-as-a-file-via-javascript

Comment: Do you want to download images only? Like pngs and jpegs?

Comment: @Tommi - 'Show' is the possibility to download the file

Comment: @JoDavid - No. I want to download any type of document. Images(png, jpeg, gif), documents (pdf, doc, txt), ...

Comment: I'd recommend you to create hidden iframe and set it's src to your file location instead. It's maybe oldschool, but it works everywhere.

Comment: @Nuno I've edited my answer to fit your requirements for different file types (other than images).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Have a look at the MDN article on [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

If you set the response of the XMLHttpRequest to [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) you could do the following:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", requestUrl);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "application/pdf"});
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(objectUrl);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

**Option 2:**
You could use [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) as the response of the XMLHttpRequest. And then maybe save it in the FileSystem ([FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/))

It may look like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", requestUrl);
xhr.responseType = "blob";

xhr.onload = function () {
    onDownloaded(this);
};
xhr.send();
```

**Option 3:**
If you only want to download and "show" images you can easily do this like so:

```
var img = new Image();

// add the onload event before setting the src
img.onload = function() {
    onImageDownloaded(img);
}

// start the download by setting the src property
img.src = requestUrl
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But my problem is a bit different. I can download pdfs or images, but when i call the REST service that returns the binary data, i don't know what is the type of the file.

Comment: You could make another request just before downloading the file to get the fileType and maybe the file name (for the UI).

Comment: why would you not use content-type header instead of hard coding type as application/pdf?

Comment: A tiny correction Jo, for a bytearray Brob parameter should be an array. ...new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});

Comment: @Maxim this answer is 3 years old. It might have changed in that time :) At the time of writing it, it worked that way (iirc).

Comment: @JoDavid Sorry, I don't like when someone's recapping my very old answers. Though, after long search I found yours and it helped to solve an issue for me it might help someone else too, just that little thing which I found in mozilla doc that you added a link to.

Comment: Where the function `onDownloaded` is defined?

Comment: Thank you for `xhr.responseType = "blob";`!

Comment: Should we revoke objectUrl?