# AJAX/PHP force file download display contents of zip file in the browser

Tags: php, ajax

Hi i'm trying to force download a zip file created from `ZipArchive()` but the file is not being downloaded instead is displayed/read in the browser.check my code below.

```
function search(item){
    var search = new XMLHttpRequest();
    search.open("POST","download.php");
    search.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(search.readyState === 4 && search.status === 200){
            // document.getElementById('tes').innerHTML = search.responseText;
        }
    }
    search.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    search.send("searchItem="+item);
}
```

download button, calls search function.

```
<button value="<?php echo "$name"; ?>" onclick="search(this.value)">Download File</button>
```

PHP code in the download.php file

```
<?php 
 $name = trim($_POST['searchItem']);
 if(!file_exists("images/$name/$name.zip")){
    //creating a zip file
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_file = "$name".'.zip';
$zip->open("images/$name/".$zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$files = scandir("images/$name/");
for ($i=2; $i < count($files) ; $i++) { 
$fi = $files[$i];
if(file_exists("images/$name/$fi")){
    $zip->addFile("images/$name/$fi", $fi);
    }
}
$zip->close();

 //force to download the zip
    $file = "images/$name/$zip_file";
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    readfile($file);
    // remove zip file from temp path
    unlink($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: and the large black square ? if i stare at it to long will i go crazy?

Comment: You might wanna check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696516/download-binary-files-with-javascript

Comment: It is doable, but better approach might be to generate a link to that file. unless you don't store it as a file but rather a binary string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't download files using `AJAX`, The simplest solution is to return the file name to Javascript and use [location.href](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) and force file download.

```
<?php
$name = trim($_POST['searchItem']);
if (!file_exists("images/$name/$name.zip")) {
    //creating a zip file
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip_file = "$name" . '.zip';
    $zip->open("images/$name/" . $zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $files = scandir("images/$name/");
    for ($i = 2; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $fi = $files[$i];
        if (file_exists("images/$name/$fi")) {
            $zip->addFile("images/$name/$fi", $fi);
        }
    }
    $zip->close();

    //force to download the zip
    $file = "images/$name/$zip_file";
    echo json_encode(['filename' => $file]); // return file name to Javascript
}
?>
```

Then in Javascript I use `location.href` to force file download

```
function search(item){
    var search = new XMLHttpRequest();
    search.open("POST","check.php");
    search.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(search.readyState === 4 && search.status === 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(search.responseText);
            window.location.href = data.filename; // force file download
        }
    };
    search.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    search.send("searchItem="+item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use to get zip file

```
 header('Content-Type: application/zip'); // ZIP file
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloadpackage.zip"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Pragma: public');
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 echo($file);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Interesting that length wasn't passed, but it worked just fine on a Mac with latest FF, Chrome, Opera, and Safari. Guess one doesn't need to pass data length header anymore.

Comment: Yep, I rarely pass content length now. Haven't had issues so far. If anyone knows why, please share.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot download a file with javascript/ajax. You're making this way more difficult than it needs to be. Forget about AJAX and just create a form or an anchor tag that links to the script that generates the ZIP file. Your page will not be redirected so there is no reason to do an XHR.

Javascript, for security reasons, does not have access to your filesystem, therefore you cannot use it to download files. What if every web site you went to was capable of adding files to your computer. That'd be bad. That's why you can't.