# my loader not working while getting file via window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I'm downloading a file via `window.location.href = '..path to server get method which returns file'`

Here is my code on button click,

```js
$(document)
            .off('click', '#btnExportToExcel')
            .on('click', '#btnExportToExcel',
                function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    indicatorStart('Loading');
                    window.location.href = '/Index/ExcelReport';
                    indicatorStop();
                    });
```

Here is my `indicatorStart()` and `indicatorStop()`,

```js
function indicatorStart(text) {
    const $loader = $($.parseHTML(`<div id="loader" class="fade show">
                                        <div id="loader-message" role="alert">${text}</div>
                                     </div>`));

    $('.page-content').append($loader);
}

function indicatorStop() {
    $('#loader').remove();
}
```

loader works when I hook this method inside ajax lifecycle but not under normal get. Only file is getting downloaded correctly. Please assist on where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Dang, this for sure aren't meant to work in any possible environment. Load your file in a binary form with this JS in order to handle download process.

Comment: That's what my server does. It returns the file in binary form. I'm using asp.net core backend and my Excel is getting downloaded perfectly

Comment: i can only repeat the first message: `"Load your file in a binary form with JS in order to handle download process"`

Comment: any samples/examples? am I doing thing wrongly? I new to js. please assist

Comment: `"Any samples?"` - sure, many samples, like this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696516. `"am I doing thing wrongly"` - yes, like i already said. This `indicatorStart/Stop` system is not supposed to work, forget about it

Comment: Note that you can track downloading progress only if you download file with JS. In any other case the browser tracks downloading process; google `xhr onprogress`