# How to pass a PDF as binary to window.open()?

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, binary, ionic-framework

I'm building an app using Cordova/ionic in which I now fetch a PDF from an API (which I am authenticated with). I then want to display this PDF in the inAppBrowser which I normally open with `window.open('http://example.com/the-file.pdf', "_blank", "location=no");`. But since I already fetched the data I cannot provide a url, but instead I want to provide the data as binary.

I searched around but I only found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9648524/1650012), which unfortunately doesn't work for me.

Does anybody know how I can pass a PDF as binary data through `window.open()`? All tips are welcome!

Comment: have you tried a data: url?

Comment: Is the PDF saved to device already? If, not can you save the binary data to a PDF on the device, then use window.open("file://...pdf")?

Comment: What was the problem you had implementing the solution you found in that answer?

Comment: Do you get your pdf as url ?

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43297424/1426222:

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,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", "mypdf", "width=700px,height=600px");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Window.open('http://docs.google.com/gview?url=YOUR_PDF_URL', "_blank", "location=no");
```